# Null pointer when calling a method in another class

Tags: java, methods, nullpointerexception, call

I have an input panel and want to call a method in another class when the button is pressed but am getting a null pointer exception. Was hoping someone might be able to tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the code causing it:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        if (ae.getSource() == resultsButton)
        {
            jbTour.processAdditionalResult();
        }

    }


public void processAdditionalResult()
    {
        System.out.println("button pressed");
    }
```

Comment: Add the exception stack traces, then we can find the error easily..

Comment: Which line is causing the exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize jbTour: `jbTour = new JBTourObject()` (or whatever) so that it is not null before the `actionPerformed` method gets invoked.

Answer (score 1):

I think I can tell even without the stack trace: `jbTour` is null.  You've declared a name of that reference type in the class that implements the `ActionListener` interface, but you never initialized it to point a new reference.

Answer (score 1):

If this throws a NullPointerException

```
jbTour.processAdditionalResult();
```

that means jbTour has not been set or is `null`.